# React Native Redirect to another page that has a class

Tags: react-native

```html
//PostImageScreen.js

import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

export default class PostScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        text: "",
        image: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPhotoPermission();
    }
   //etc...
   
   
   
   
//ImagesScreen.js

import PostScreen from "./PostImageScreen";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

const redirects = createStackNavigator({
  Post: { screen: PostScreen }
});

export default class ImagesScreen extends React.Component {

  // buttonPressed = async () => {
  buttonPressed = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Post');
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (

  <Background>
    
    <Header>Image Display Screen</Header>
    
    <Button mode="outlined" onPress={() => logoutUser()}>
      Logout
    </Button>
    <ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={() => navigate('Post')}>
          </ActionButton>
  </Background>
    )
  }
```

So right now I am not getting a response from my button and just curious as to a workaround?  Previously ImagesScreen was a function and I converted it to a class to try using a stack navigator but still can't figure a work around.

I just want the ActionButton to redirect to the PostImageScreen so that I can add an image with a comment then post it.  The posting works, tested it before hand just having trouble with redirecting.

follow up ***
tried this as well and still getting nothing when the button is pressed.

```html
const ImagesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  
    return (

  <Background>
    
    <Header>Image Display Screen</Header>
    
    <Button mode="outlined" onPress={() => logoutUser()}>
      Logout
    </Button>
    {/* <ActionButton buttonColor="#1E73C1" onPress={() => navigate('Post')}>
          </ActionButton> */}
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("PostImageScreen")}
        >
          <Text >Add an Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  </Background>
    )
}

export default memo(ImagesScreen);
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: unfortunately no, before when imagesScreen was just a function and not a class and I tried to call postScreen from postImageScreen, I got Error postScreen is an object etc etc.  but as the code is now, none

Comment: Structure is wrong. Please look at react navigation documentation

Comment: @NijatAliyev I looked through it again and changed ImagesScreen back to a class and tried onPress={() =this.props.navigation.navigate("PostImageScreen");             Still nothing, any idea what else is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured it out!!

I have a switch navigator within a stacknavigator, which control my user auth and then switch to tabs navigation when logged in. That navigation was blocking my navigation calls!

4 hours but I finally got it thank god lol.